# How to add Horizontal scrolling news ticker from an RSS or headlines from other site in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rss, news-ticker

How to add horizontal scrolling news ticker from any news website to Wordpress?

I've tried all RSS plugins in wordpress but they dont scroll horizontally

There is an example in this website http://lighthouse.com.tr/eng/ above the currency rates. The news are also coming from investing.com

Comment: i can see a horizontal scrolling news ticker but not vertical

Comment: So sorry, i meant horizontal. Just edited my text.

Comment: Can you help? thanks.

Comment: take a look at https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG perhaps - should be fairly easy to use this to display news headlines or whatever or search on google for "horizontal ticker" ~ it looks like there are plenty available for Wordpress too

Comment: this one is easy but i dont know hot to pull headlines from news sites for example in this code?